# Which Mail rule processed a message?

Tags: macos, mail.app, mail-rules

I have lots of mail rules that sort incoming mail into different folders. Today a message got put into a folder it didn't belong in. There are over 40 rules that move messages into this particular folder, and I'm not sure which one matched this message inappropriately, so I can fix the criteria. I tried searching `MessageRules.plist` in a text editor for all these rules, and none of the criteria looked like they should match, but there must have been something I missed.

Is there a way to know which one did it? I know that I can make a rule set the color of a message, so I could move the message back into my Inbox and use Apply Rules. But with so many rules, it's not really practical to give them all colors that I can distinguish.